# The depth sensitivity of the Koszul complex

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Assume $R$ is a local ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Call $K^R$ the *Koszul complex* of $R$ (over a minimal set of generators of the maximal ideal) and call $K^M$ the complex $K^R\otimes M$. I know the $H_i(K^R)=0$ if $i>\mathrm{edim}\;R-\mathrm{depth}\;R$ (where edim means the minimum number of generators of the maximal ideal).

> How can I prove that $H_i(K^M)=0$ if $i>\mathrm{edim}\;R-\mathrm{depth}\;M$?

Comment: Let $R=k[[x]]$ and $M=k[[x]]/(x)$. Let $K^R$ be $R\rightarrow^x R$. Then $K^R\otimes M$ is $M\rightarrow^0 M$, which has higher cohomology.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the question carefully. So, what I would do is the following. Take a regular sequence to M, and just expand it to have a minimal set of generators of the maximal ideal. Then "the regular sequence does not give you any cohomology", so $H^i(K^M)=0$ if $i>edim R-depth M$.

Comment: I'd say that this property is better known as the [*rigidity of the Koszul complex*](http://books.google.ro/books?id=foG0rKKKXboC&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=%22rigidity+of+the+koszul+complex%22&source=bl&ots=zmqbMx1a3J&sig=tJzSOK8dkF55VlW--umPQLAcgsw&hl=ro&sa=X&ei=6DfZUdPSMM3XPOS4gaAM&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22rigidity%20of%20the%20koszul%20complex%22&f=true) rather than "depth sensitivity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is an immediate application of Theorem 1.6.16 in Bruns and Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*.